# Flask: lost the session in restful server

Tags: python, flask, flask-oauthlib

I am trying to create a simple web application in order to better study how it works. The idea is that the user can login via twitter, and after that can access different functions on the front end. I can make the user authenticate via twitter, but I lost the session from one request to another. I use `python3` `flask` and `flask-oauthlib`

```
from flask import Flask, request, url_for, session, redirect, flash
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_oauthlib.client import OAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
oauth = OAuth()

@app.route('/login')
def login():
    callback_url = url_for('oauthorized', next=request.args.get('next'))
    return twitter.authorize(callback=callback_url or request.referrer or None)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('twitter_oauth', None)
    return redirect(app.config['FRONT_END_URL'])

@app.route('/oauthorized')
def oauthorized():
    frontend_url = app.config['FRONT_END_URL']
    resp = twitter.authorized_response()

    if resp is None:
        flash('You denied the request to sign in.')
        return redirect(frontend_url)
    elif resp['screen_name'] not in allowed_twitter:
        flash('You dont have premission')
        return redirect(frontend_url)

    access_token = resp['oauth_token']
    session['access_token'] = access_token
    session['screen_name'] = resp['screen_name']

    session['twitter_token'] = (
        resp['oauth_token'],
        resp['oauth_token_secret']
    )

    flash('You were successfully logged in')
    return redirect(frontend_url + "/accionDirecta")

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    print(session)  # Is always empty

    access_token = session.get('access_token')
    if access_token is None:
        return("Not login")
    else:
        return("login")
```

The `print(session)` inside `oauthorized()` is correct, but when the user ,after login, make a get to `/test` using `jquery $ajax`, I the session is empty. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `$ajax get`. By default, ajax don't include your cookies, so you must force to use. In the `$ajax` you must add:

`crossDomain: true,
 xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }`

And this force to use your cookies.